# How to verify if a checkbox is checked with jqLite in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-jqlite

I want to know if a checkbox is checked using jqLite in angularjs. I'm using a directive to check and verify if the value is `true` or `false`. I tried this code `angular.element('#myCheckbox').val()`, but the value returned was `false`.

```
<input type="checkbox" id='myCheckbox' my-directive>
```

angular.js

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(angular.element('#myCheckbox').val());
            },
        };
})
```

Comment: Why not `element.checked`?

Comment: Why not bind it using ng-model and then check the model value?  Jqlite should be used in very limited instances where angular doesn't have existing coverage.

Comment: Consider using the AngularJS built-in validation system. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation). AngularJS provides basic implementation for most common HTML5 input types: (text, number, url, email, date, radio, **checkbox**), as well as some directives for validation (required, pattern, minlength, maxlength, min, max).